# Responsive display for small picture on whole screen

Tags: android, html, ios, css, responsive-design

I have a picture (dimension 320px X 480px) of same size like normal phone device size. I want to make the display responsive for this picture.
I want to display the picture as it is in the mobile device.
While, I want to show the image in the center in the desktop (and in other big) devices[image]

Note: 
Red squares with round corner are showing the picture in the screenshot above.
Black squares are showing the device in the screenshot above.

My HTML is below, (this HTML works fine for the mobile devices. But this does not work from desktop)

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <img src="images/picture.jpg" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;height:auto;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 539px) {
    table {
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

You can add `position:fixed` or `absolute`

```
@media (max-width: 539px) {
        table {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100vw;
            height:100vh;
        }
}
```

Comment: Download solution from the following page - http://www.searchofday.com/responsive-display-for-small-picture/